# Spring Security Active Directoty Authentication

Tags: spring, security, active-directory

I am using Spring Security and Active Directly for authentication. Below my configuration

```
     registry
.ldapAuthentication()
.ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(customLdapAuthoritiesPopulator)
.userDnPatterns("cn={0},cn=Users")
        .contextSource() .managerDn("cn=Administrator,cn=Users,cn=COMPANY,cn=COM,cn=TN") 
.managerPassword("xxxxxxx")
.url("ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:389/cn=COMPANY,cn=COM,cn=TN") ;
```

When I am trying to connect with a valid user I've got this log:

```
    23:30:49.321 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
    23:30:49.322 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: ben 
    23:30:49.344 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Attempting to bind as cn=ben,cn=Users,cn=COMPANY,cn=COM,cn=TN
    23:30:49.345 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - Removing pooling flag for user cn=ben,cn=Users,cn=COMPANY,cn=COM,cn=TN 
23:30:52.371 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Failed to bind as cn=ben,cn=Users: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was a stupid mistake: I used CN instead of DC.